# Rename the property in json serialization for anonymous

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am wondering is anyway to rename properties in JSON serialization?

```
var obj =  data.Select(p => new
           {
               id = p.Id,
               text = p.Name,
               a_attr = new { data_extra = new { Weight = p.Weight, MaxScore = p.MaxScore} },
            }).ToList();
```

data_extra should be rename to data-extra after serialization

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just create a named type so you can apply appropriate name attributes?

Comment: Is there in fact any reason for data-extra / data_extra as a separate object in the first place?  Depending on how many items there are in your array, you could dramatically decrease the response's size by simply adding `Weight` and `MaxScore` properties directly to the root object when there seems to be only one per object at any rate.

Comment: @Jon Bellamy, the java-script component needs this format.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Just for easier maintenance, we already have dozen classes for ad-hoc java script serializations.

Comment: @Nima, OK, so what are you using to serialise it?

Comment: @Jon, I am using JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: @Nima OK, I'd recommend switching to DataContractSerialiser for renaming variables.  I use it alot.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to DataContractSerializer ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)) for ease of renaming property values.  You will also need to create some small classes for your data.  See below:

```
[DataContract]
public class ReturnObject // Feel free to name to something more suitable
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int Id {get; set;} // Int assumed
    [DataMember(Name="text")]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    [DataMember(Name="a_attr")]
    public ReturnObjectAttributes Attributes {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class ReturnObjectAttributes // Feel free to name to something more suitable
{
    [DataMember(Name="data-extra")]
    public ExtraData ReturnObjectAttrData {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class ExtraData // Feel free to name to something more suitable
{
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Weight{get; set;} // Decimal assumed
    [DataMember]
    public decimal MaxScore {get; set;} // Decimal assumed
}

// Then process
data.Select(p => new ReturnObject()
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name,
    Attributes = new ReturnObjectAttributes()
    {
        ExtraData = new ReturnObjectAttrData()
        {
            Weight = p.Weight,
            MaxScore = p.MaxScore
        }
}).ToList();
```

All you then need to do is serialise it - see information in provided MSDN link.